# Changes in ForkJoinPool implementation

Tags: java, fork-join, forkjoinpool

I've encountered a strange problem while using ForkJoinPool in JDK 1.8.0_40 while simply reverting back to 1.8.0 solves the problem without any change in code.

The code takes a List of runnables, converts them to List of ForkJoinTask with ForkJoinTask.adapt()
For each list I use an enclosing ForkJoinTask that calls ForkJoinTask.invokeAll() on its list in the exec() method.
(https://github.com/mich8bsp/forkjoinpool-reproducer)

The problem I see is that once in a while invoking this ForkJoinTask will block indefinitely. I do see other threads running, but the thread that called "invoke" is stuck.

Comparing the sources of jdk 1.8.0 and 1.8.0_40 I see a lot of changes in ForkJoinPool.java and ForkJoinTask.java

Is there any documentation for this change? Any lead to what might cause the problem?

(The version of JVM I'm using is Java Hotspot 64-Bit Server VM build 25.40-b25)

Edit: maybe this change is the cause? https://bugs.java.com/view_bug.do?bug_id=8056248